# Book about a man living in the '70s or '80s who falls asleep one night and wakes up in a utopian future

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I am looking for a book about a man from the 1970s or '80s who falls asleep one night and wakes up in a utopian future. It was also written back then. This isn't a recent book.

In the future, he meets a woman who is showing him around or something. Everyone is bald because no one cares about their appearance and no one is ashamed of their bodies. I'm pretty sure the future people all have telepathy too. He eventually falls asleep again and wakes back up in his own time, but keeps trying to go back.

The author is a woman. I can't remember her name, but I remember it being unique. And the title is a number, like a year.

Comment: The women in the future were bald too?

Comment: Was this a full novel? I seem to remember a short story like this in _Omni_ magazine.

Answer (score 5):

This might be ["2150: The Macro Love Story"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1327712), also titled "2150 A.D."  According to the ISFDB, it was originally published in 1971 with authors Don and Thea Plym, but was later republished as being by only Thea Alexander.

The protagonist, Jon Lake, living in the 1970s, has dreams in which he lives in a future utopian 2150 society.  On his first visit, he meets the woman Lea, who introduces him to the society.  Although the people are not bald, they generally have short hair.  From Chapter 4:

> I was impressed with the sheer physical size and beauty of my fellow Alpha members. I was also surprised at the lack of hair. Of the five males my hair was the longest, and it was short by 1976 standards. Even among the girls the longest hair was Carol's, which was no more than four inches at most.
> When I asked Carol about this she informed me that they did not value hair because they were not vain about their appearances. It was simpler, she assured me, to keep their hair short.

The society is regulated by the unifying so-called Macro philosophy and people have lots of psychic superpowers, including telepathy.  From Chapter 4 again:

> One's level of awareness was indicated by the color of his tunic. The tunic, I learned, was a perfectly accurate reflection of one's aura, which was an unfailingly accurate indicator of one's state of being, mentally, emotionally, spiritually, and physically. ...
> These degrees of awareness were based on the extent to which a person demonstrated the three Macro qualities: love, wisdom, and leadership, in that order of importance, and the seven Macro powers: clairvoyance, telepathy, precognition, retro cognition, psycho kinesis, telekinesis, and astral projection. [See C.I. Excerpts].

Jon Lake goes back and forth between the 1970s and 2150 for a while in an attempt to gain enough "macro awareness" to live in 2150 permanently, but unfortunately doesn't succeed.

The book is connected with a [self-help group](https://macrosociety.org/).  There used to be a Wikipedia article about this book but it was deleted because the book was not important enough.  However, an [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20220527220537/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2150_AD) is still available.